# Three.js : could not initialise shader VALIDATE_STATUS: false, gl error [0].

Tags: three.js, webgl

Three.js : could not initialise shader VALIDATE_STATUS: false, gl error [0].
I am receiving  this error message in javascript console log. On google Chrome Version 31.0.1650.48 m. Any help would be appreciated reagrding this issue ..

Comment: what shader are you using, show some source code of the shader and maybe also initialization?

Comment: We are facing this issue from yesterday in our application and previously it is working fine. Our 3D Geometry is creating but visible  and getting above error message in console log.          var material =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color : 0x888888,side: THREE.DoubleSide,specular: 0x333333, shininess: 10 
  });

Comment: Even the example source code doesn't work anymore with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT
OK I found the error, at least mine, it's the shader precision, it should be the same in the vertex shader and fragment shader. I was mixing precision highp float and mediump float
(http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=309527)

---

Exaclty same issue, my program use 2 shaders and can switch between them. One of the two doesn't work anymore since yesterday without any modification!
(Chrome native gl 31.0.1650.57 m)